# Catering problem. How many will eat wheat sugar and are vegetarians (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

You are catering the awards banquet. One hundred will be attending. 8 do not eat wheat,sugar or meat. 68 eat wheat, 48 eat wheat but are vegetarians, 18 eat wheat but not sugar,50 eat wheat and sugar, 20 people eat wheat and are not vegetarians, 20 eat sugar and not wheat, 70 guests eat sugar and 47 are vegetarians that eat sugar  How many eat wheat and sugar but are vegetarians? how many vegetarians are there

For this problem i created a ven diagram with sections labeled A-G. however i had difficulty placing the right values into the right sections. i understand that in the end you would want to get something like  AintersectionBintersectionC. (which would be the middle part of the diagram) perhaps i am just not visualizing this correctly but its causing me some heart ache.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, determine those people who eat wheat, sugar, or meat. These people lie at the center of the venn diagram.
2. Then, subtract this number from the people who eat (wheat and meat), (wheat and sugar), and (meat and sugar) to determine the amount of people who eat two of the specified food groups.
3. Then take the people who eat (wheat), (sugar), and (meat) and subtract those that eat all three and those that eat two to determine those that only eat the specified category of foods.
4. The remaining people do not eat any of the specified foods.